# JSON Schema Restricting the Length of a Integer

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

While restricting strings can be defined as

```
"last_name": {
            "type": "string",
            "maxLength": 30,
            "minLength": 1
          }
```

It does not work on `integer` as type, bec minimum and maximum is a range.

Is there a keyword we can use to specify length on integer using json-schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I have solved this is using a regex pattern. Which works well.

```
"mobile_country_code": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^[0-9]{2,3}$",
          },
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in the JSON schema found here: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/numeric.html?highlight=integer

> Ranges of numbers are specified using a combination of the
> minimum and maximum keywords, (or exclusiveMinimum and
> exclusiveMaximum for expressing exclusive range).
>
> If x is the value being validated, the following must hold true:
>
> x ≥ minimum x > exclusiveMinimum x ≤ maximum x < exclusiveMaximum
> While you can specify both of minimum and exclusiveMinimum or both of
> maximum and exclusiveMaximum, it doesn’t really make sense to do so.
>
> {   "type": "number",   "minimum": 0,   "exclusiveMaximum": 100 }

I think the keywords you are looking for are minimum and maximum or exclusiveMinimum and exclusiveMaximum.

Edit: After reading the question a bit more let me clarify what I mean.

I see you want to have the **length** of the integer and not the actual range, however if you want the length to be lets say 8 characters, you can pick the range between 0 and 99999999 to get the same effect.

Currently there are not a JSON specification available that specifies the exact length of a number.